# How to check if the header is added when using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, kotlin, httpurlconnection

I don't know how to write the test case for testing that a header has been successfully added.

```
val connection = URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
connection.setRequestProperty("a", "b")
assertEquals("b", connection.getHeaderField("a"))
```

Basically, `getHeaderField` will return null. And the result of `getHeaderFields` doesn't include this `a` field as well. I inspected the connection object. There is a property called `userHeaders` in the runtime, but I can't access that when I am coding. Seems not included in the `HttpURLConnection` layout.

How to assert my headers has been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're using `setRequestProperty(...)` why not assert using `getRequestProperty(...)`?

```
val connection = URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
val headers = mapOf("a" to "b")
connection.setRequestProperty("a", "b")
assertEquals("b", connection.getRequestProperty("a")) // OK
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But why the header that I add doesn't included in the result of `getHeaderFields()` or `getHeaderField("a")`?